# Creating stub file for static nested class

Tags: java, c

I have problems using `javah` to create c-stubs (h-file) for static nested classes in Java.

Can someone verify that this is not working since `javah` does not find the outer class?

Also I would like to know why it should be impossible to create a stub file for an (static) nested class.

Comment: What commands are you running? What do you see, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I did something wrong I tried it twice and it failed. Now i tried it with another class and it works. Do not know why but it seams that it can not work properly with certain annotations that are placed else where (the other class has a @Test annotation. It was not finding it but the error complained about the outer class.

Comment: `static inner` is a contradiction in terms. You mean `static nested`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to an @Test annotation but javah did complained about the outer class (where this notation was applied to a method) as being unable to find the outer class.